# Vanilla JavaScript to Save and Restore Caret Position When HTML Updated in Content Editable DIV

Tags: javascript, selection, caret

I know there many similar questions with answers on **StackOverflow** and **Google** and I've tried many and none of them works. So I will post my own code below and hopefully someone can help. Thanks in advance.

*Note: there might be typos in below codes as I manually typed this question. I've checked and apologise for any inconvenience if they confuse you.*

> The logic I'm trying to achieve in that `contenteditable` DIV:

1. User types in the DIV
2. Meanwhile an event listener is checking the text user enters and filter with pre-defined keywords array such as `['apple', 'banana']`. Filtered text will be wrapped in the HTML and write back to the DIV.
3. While achieving above, user doesn't lose mouse caret which means this scanning and replacing procedure should be constantly happening in the background and doesn't affect user's editing.

> The code:

#### HTML (Before Process)

```
<div id="editor">
    Mr Jenkins has an apple and a banana.
</div>
```

#### HTML (After Processed)

```
<div id="editor">
    Mr Jenkins has an <u>apple</u> and a <u>banana</u>.
</div>
```

#### JavaScript (It's in `vue` so I skipped other parts here and display in `vanilla` way here)

> **Plan A** to use pre-defined selection variable

This throws error "DOMException:
`Failed to execute 'collapse' on 'Selection': There is no child at offset 7"`

```
// Global variable to store the offset value when DOM content loaded
// The input event of the #editor element is listened but skipped here
var caretPosition,
    selection = window.getSelection();

function scanText() {
    let editor = document.getElementById('editor');

    // Save the position
    caretPosition = selection.focusOffset;

    // Scan and replace text
    editor.innerHTML = filterText(); // Function filterText will return HTML as in above example

    // Restore the position
    selection.collapse(editor, caretPosition);
}
```

> **Plan B** to use get selection on the go

This doesn't throw any errors but caret position is weird
The `focusOffset` value is far smaller than the real `focusOffset` value.
For example, if `focusOffset` in **Plan A** is `100`, it's `9` in **Plan B**.
So it always restore at the incorrect position

```
function scanText() {
    let editor = document.getElementById('editor');

    // Save the position
    caretPosition = window.getSelection().focusOffset;

    // Scan and replace text
    editor.innerHTML = filterText(); // Function filterText will return HTML as in above example

    // Restore the position
    window.getSelection().collapse(editor, caretPosition);
}
```

> **Plan C** to use range

"IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': There is no child at offset 5."

```
function scanText() {
    let editor = document.getElementById('editor'),
        offsets, range = new Range();

    // Save the range
    // It starts at 5 and ends at 101 though I only placed cursor at the end of the text
    if (window.getSelection().rangeCount) {
        offsets = [
            window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset, // 5
            window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endOffset // 101
        ];
    }

    // Scan and replace text
    editor.innerHTML = filterText(); // Function filterText will return HTML as in above example

    // Restore the range
    range.setStart(editor, offsets[0]); // Set start container to editor and start offset as 5
    range.setEnd(editor, offsets[1]); // Set end container to editor and end offset as 101
}
```

Comment: I tried all day. Looks like the solution to this is going to be a real pain. Although you can `getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endOffset`, which will give you the offset on the node which the selection occurs, you cannot tell what node it occurs on even if you attach Events to the children. I think you want to make sure your nested nodes aren't really nested.

Comment: Thanks @stackslave, I've started a workaround solution not to use this feature (in a new branch) at all but I will keep monitoring this post and it would be so awesome and graceful to find a real solution of this problem. So far the offset can be saved separately if I don't want a saved range object to be changed when HTML is updated but writing it to the element is such a pain. It's not nested though.

Comment: I'm going to go as far as to say it's actually a JavaScript design flaw that's been around for a long time and never fixed. I would think something like `getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer` would give me the child node, if my caret is on one, but it does not. Seems very strange since you can `getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endOffset` which is an index within the child. Also, it seems contenteditable child nodes cannot take keyboard or input Events. It would also be nice if contenteditables would pass an `EventObject` with `EventObject.relatedTarget` support for nested nodes.